# JQuery animate() doesn't work in FF or Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a short piece of CoffeeScript and this code scrolls my page to top with animation. It works  in Chromium but there is some issue in FF or Opera.

```
$('#scrolltop').click ->
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000)
```

But code like `$(document).scrollTop 10` works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Animate the root element as well:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000)
```